# Best practices for storing data objects that differentiate by one field?

Tags: storage, implementation

Lets say for example that I have a list of two types of cars. Red cars and blue cars. Would it be better to store all of my cars in one data type and include a differentiating 'type' field that would either be red or blue. Or would it be better to create a redCar and blueCar data type, then store each type of car in its respective list?

My issue with creating one data type, then differentiating based on type is that I have to filter every time I render these lists in a view. On the other hand, it seems stupid to have two data types that only have one small difference.

Answer (score 0):

After researching this issue a bit more, I've come to the conclusion that I should create one data object and filter based on the differentiating fields.

Comment: Yep. I don't know what you're using as storage or which language you use, so I don't understand the problem with "I have to filter every time I render these lists in a view".

How do you filter? SQL?

FYI, the differentiating "type" field is often called **discriminator column**.